# Open message in gmail app from ios app

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to open a specific message within the gmail app from within my own ios app using the googlegmail:// scheme. I can launch the gmail app using this but I need to load a specific message.

Comment: I searched for this and I found:  https://swiftlang.eu/community/5014-gmail-api-request-a-message/0    It is written that  you should add query parameters like:  query.urlQueryParameters = ["identifier": id] .     identifier: The ID of the message to retrieve.